# Variable mass system in fluid mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

A tank, initially at rest , is filled with water to a height H=4m. A small orifice is made at the bottom of the wall.Find the velocity attained by the tank when it becomes completely empty. (Assume the mass of the tank and friction to be negligible.)[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried. Sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Hi Shikhar and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: This looks less like a  "fluid mechanics" problem and more like a "how to apply conservation of momentum and energy properly" problem.

Comment: Sorta the opposite of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153361/25301

Comment: @RichardMetzler Seems like a mix of Torricelli's law and conservation of momentum.  I could see why this might come up when talking about fluids.

Comment: @JMac: true. I had forgotten it had a specific name... seemed like straightforward conservation of energy to me.

Comment: @RichardMetzler At the end of the day, that's really all Torricelli's law is, but it's a bit easier to digest if someone already worked out one of the relationships.